# why set the IV / Key in AesManaged when setting them in the CreateDecryptor method works just fine?

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

In the AesManaged class there's the [IV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.iv?view=net-5.0) and [Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.key?view=net-5.0) properties. In the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=net-5.0#examples these properties are set and then passed to the `CreateDecryptor` method. But, in my testing, one can decrypt ciphertext's successfully even without setting the IV / Key methods:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/569976
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
          return bytes;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var ciphertext = StringToByteArray("10f42fd95857ed2775cfbc4b471bc213");

        var aes = new AesManaged();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        var iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(ciphertext);
        CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt);
        String plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(plaintext);
    }
}
```

So why set them with the properties at all?

I guess you'd still need to set the mode (CBC, ECB, CTR, etc) via the properties but setting the IV / Key via the properties seems redundant and unnecessary to me?

Comment: It is redundant and unnecessary. It's probably there to support different usage and software design paradigms. You should probably choose one way or the other. Personally think setting the key and iv in the Create method is safest.

Comment: srDecrypt already contains the IV.  Follow the code backwards : csDecrytp : decrypt : decryptor : key,iv.